# Laravel testing not complete on online server

Tags: linux, laravel, testing, phpunit

When I ran php artisan test on online server (linux), it always finished at certain test without any reason. But when I test it on local server (windows), it finished completely. I googled all possible solution but nothing works.

**Things that I've tried**

- I ran php artisan test --filter one by one on online server, all worked well
- At first I assumed it's because of the server cpu usage becomes 100% when I was running php artisan test, so I put "sleep(1)" on every test. CPU usage was decreased! but the test still finished at certain point (on same test file)
- I separate test between folders by adding testsuite on phpunit.xml. It worked well until it test a folder that contains so many DB transactions.

What should I do to make a single command php artisan test running completely? I don't want to type every single command with filter or testsuite. Any respond would be appreciated, thank you very much

Comment: Wow, never run tests on production!

Comment: @Maksim oh sorry, I mean online server that focus on testing only hehe. Anyway, do you have any idea how?

Comment: did u try to run phpunit directly? and, if problem on database - give more resources to database?

Comment: @Maksim I did it, still stopped at certain point and same test file like I ran php artisan test. here's the test result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4FmW12tO47Jpp38498G4Ss6p6cDARMH/view?usp=sharing Thank you so much for the respond, really apreciated it

Comment: @GilangPangestu you have a nice warning there, I would fix it and try again. How much RAM do you have on that server ? Are you using a Docker container and is the same for both local and server ? Could any PHP configuration vary on local and server ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you for the answer, I've fixed the warning but the problem still persist, here's the second result : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x5qcIUcx7GkJIhyVDVx3AJA62EMaaZr9/view?usp=sharing and the server has 16GB RAM, I'm not using docker on both local and server. And your last question made me think it could be possible, but idk where it might be different, coz the .env config are all same except for DB and app info

Comment: @matiaslauriti Already solved! it was silly because php.ini limited ram usage to 32MB only, so I ran php artisan test -d memory_limit=512M and all test worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALREADY SOLVED**

It's because the server has limitation ram usage to 32MB only, so I ran php artisan test -d memory_limit=512M and it worked well perfectly